# Can mono produce valid xhtml?

Tags: xhtml, mono, monodevelop

I installed Mono and MonoDevelop 2.2 on my Windows PC.
Created a default C# ASP.NET Web Application project.
Here's the Default.aspx it created:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="test.Default" %>    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">    
<html>    
<head runat="server">    
    <title>Default</title>    
</head>    
<body>    
    <form id="form1" runat="server">    
        <asp:Button id="button1" runat="server" Text="Click me!" OnClick="button1Clicked" />    
    </form>    
</body>    
</html>
```

When I run it it feeds this html to the browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head><title>
    Default
</title></head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTQ2OTkzNDMyMWRkjWseIg+2HCgaNiY+XHmVKEq/CFg=" />
</div>

<div>

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWAgLB5qLABwKs34rGBvJAYc3UJn3AcjSPjq8DVpMxclAk" />
</div>

        <input type="submit" name="button1" value="Click me!" id="button1" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

XHTML validation fails with 3 errors:
1. Line 3, Column 1: Missing xmlns attribute for element html. The value should be: http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
2. Line 8, Column 13: there is no attribute "name"
3. Line 17, Column 71: document type does not allow element "input" here; missing one of "p", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "div", "pre", "address", "fieldset", "ins", "del" start-tag

Is there some setting I'm missing?

Comment: Is it mono that produces wrong XHTML or just a template? In VS it's up to me to provide valid XHTML but the ide supports me by doing validations.

Comment: I'm not sure. I've added more info to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: [How to: Configure XHTML Rendering in ASP.NET Web Sites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178159.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the problem is in the Microsoft .NET runtime.
In MonoDevelop under Project menu there is sub-menu `Active Runtime`.
Switching it from Microsoft .NET to Mono fixes the problem!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this has to do with Mono.  Change `<html>` to `<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>`.

Comment: That will get rid of the first error, but what do I do with the second one?